# Xcode9.4のPlaygroundでコンソールに実行結果を表示させるには

Tags: xcode, swift4

同じようなご質問をされている方も見かけたのですが、どの方法でも解決できませんでした。
Plyaygroundでコンソールにprint関数の実行結果を表示させる方法についてご教授ください。
なお、Xcode Project側では問題なくコンソール表示されております。

既に試した方法
・Runningセクションで「Show debugger with Variables & Console View」を指定

・Activate Consoleを表示
　実行方法の指定は「Manually Run」

特にエラー表示がある訳でもなく、コンソールに何も表示されないので困っております。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 標準状態では、コードを入力して`print`関数等の呼び出しが実行されれば自動的に表示される、が正解で何もする必要はありません。手動実行に設定した場合は、コードを入力して青色▶︎の実行ボタンをクリックしてください。注意点としては、・コードを入力して(あるいは実行ボタンを押して)から実際に実行されるまでに数分かかることがある、・Xcode/Playgroundのバグにはまってしまう(再現条件は不明だがしょっちゅう起こります)と **Running** の標示が出たまま永久に(?)実行が始まらないことがある、と言うところでしょうか。後者の場合でしたら、一度保存してXcodeを終了し、再度起動したXcodeのFile>Openからそのplaygroundドキュメントを開きなおすと(数分かかる場合がありますが)実行されるようです。

Comment: OOPer様、ご回答頂きありがとうございます。同じような事象を経験された方にご意見を頂けたことに感謝いたします。Xcodeを再起動したところ、「Xcodeはデバッグを続けるために〜」というような趣旨のポップアップとパスワードの入力を求められました。調べたところ、Playgroundでコンソールに値を表示させることはデバッグにあたるようで、OSの認証が必要のようです。パスワード入力後にPlaygroundエディタが起動し、1分くらい待つとコンソールにprint関数の値が表示されました。Xcode Projectでは認証なしでデバッグもエミュレータ起動もできていたので、こういった動作仕様だと知らずに質問してしまいました。Playgroundについては、初回起動時はコード入力後に一旦再起動してからOS認証を突破しないとデバッグ機能が有効にならないようです。二度目以降の起動時には認証なしでデバッグできました。

Comment: ご経験を共有していただきありがとうございます。実は、私自身は「Xcodeはデバッグを続けるために〜」と言うメッセージは見た覚えがないのですが、遥か前に見たっきり忘れているだけなのかもしれません。コメントの内容そのままで大丈夫だと思うのですが、ご回答として投稿していただければ、多くの方に参考になる事柄かと思います。お時間を取ってみていただけるようお願いします。

Comment: OOPer様、アドバイスをくださいましてありがとうございます。自分の質問に自分で回答を付けるのは不思議な感じもしますが、解答欄に補足情報を含めて投稿いたしました。依然として、どういう設定である場合にこのような手順が追加されるのかは不明のため、この点については触れておりません。Xcode Project側であれば「作業用ユーザーを開発者のグループに追加」すると表示されなくなるとの情報もネット上で見かけました。

Answer (score 1):

Xcoede 9.4.1で、コード断片を書けば、下部のペインにprint文で出力した結果が、
ソースコードの右のグレイの部分にも変数の値が出力されているはずです。
更に、ソースコード右のグレイの変数の内容の横の3本線の様なアイコンをクリックすると
詳細な内容がポップあっうウィンドウで表示されるかと思います。

うちでは、添付の図のようになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

概ねコメント欄に記載したとおりですが、情報を補足します。

初めてPlaygroundのエディタを起動した場合、コードを入力しても実行ボタン（デフォルトはAutomatically Run）をクリックしても、コンソールに実行結果は表示されません。
このような場合、一旦XcodeをQuitし、Welcom to Xcodeから作成済みPlyagroundファイルを開くと、以下のポップアップが表示される状態となります。この認証をパスするとコンソールに実行結果を表示させることができるようになります。

「Xcodeはデバッグを続行するために別のプロセスを制御する必要があります。許可するにはパスワードを入力してください。」

ここでOSに設定したパスワードを入力するとコンソールにライブで実行結果を表示することができます。キャンセルした場合、Manually Runを指定している場合には、実行ボタンをクリックした際に再度同じポップアップが表示されますので、ここでパスワードを入力すればコンソール出力が有効になります。

OSを再起動しない限り、Xcodeだけを再起動しても一旦認証を通していれば二度目以降はパスできますが、OS自体を再起動した場合には、最初にPlaygroundファイルを開こうとした際に改めて認証を求められます。
どのような設定の場合にこういった手順が追加されるのか詳細は把握しておりませんが、権限の問題のようです。通常は認証がなくても使用できるようです。

なお、Xcode Projectでエミュレータ起動時に上記メッセージに類似の内容が表示されることがあるとの情報もありますが、本件質問は若干状況が異なります。本件ではXcode Projectでは認証を求められることなくデバッグもエミュレータ起動も実行できており、あくまでPlayground使用時のみの現象です。